# Flutter TextField calls onSubmitted unexpectedly

Tags: flutter, widget, textfield, onsubmit

My case is I have a widget with *TextField* used for search. When I type something in *TextField* the cross icon become visible in *suffixIcon* (to clear). I **do not do** search and just click the cross icon **to clear** the entered input but *onSubmitted* is called and search executed!!! But I don't need it! I **do not submit** the text input, I **cancel** it!!

```dart
final searchClear = ValueNotifier(false);
final searchController = TextEditingController();

// in initState method:

searchController.addListener(() {
  searchClear.value = searchController.text.isNotEmpty;
});

// in build method:

TextField(
  ...
  controller: searchController,
  suffixIcon: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
    valueListenable: searchClear,
    builder: (_,visible,child) {
      return Visibility(
        visible: visible,
        child:child,
      );
    },
    child: InkWell(
      child: Icon(Icons.close),
      onTap: () {
        searchController.clear();
        searchFocus.unfocus();
      }
    ),
  ),
  onSubmitted: (value) {
    if(value.isEmpty) {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(searchFocus);
    } else {
      widget.search(value);
    }

  }
),
```

P.S. Any ideas to work around this?

Comment: Can you please put your code in the post? I would assume that you should check "onPressed" call from suffixIcon: 
_suffixIcon: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: () {}_

Comment: @vinipx, code is added not completely but idea is clean.What do you mean _should check_? The problem is I tap on clear icon and _onSubmitted_ executed with last entered (not cleared yet!) search text.

Comment: Ok, there was a recent thread about same issue - [check it] here(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36324)

They published a solution - [please check it here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36948#issuecomment-599797015)

_"The workaround is to clear the controller after the next frame or some delay. I've read it's because clicking the suffix icon causes the field to gain focus, and then it attempts to select text, but there is no text."_

Comment: @vinipx, unfortunaly it does not help. I enter text (without search execution) and clear it (via suffix icon). Search is executed because _onSubmitted_ is called BEFORE _onTap_

Comment: @vinipx, in my case when suffixIcon clicked the TextField generates onEditCompleted and onSubmitted.